# More Violations In Sonar then Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

We are using only FxCop and StyleCop rules in Jenkins and Sonar.
But we are getting more no. of Violations on Sonar Dashboard then in Jenkins.
Jenkins in using 318 rules (FxCop & Stylecop Combined) whereas Sonar is using only 130 rules (FxCop & Stylecop Combined). 
But still we get more no. of Violations on Sonar Dashboard then on Jenkins.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

And Jenkins shows result of FxCop and StyleCop seperately, whereas Sonar merge result of FxCop and StyleCop and display them. Does any one know how can we seprate the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several explanations why you get more violations in Sonar:

- the FxCop and StyleCop rules are not configured with the same parameters (threshold, ...) between Sonar and Jenkins. This is the first thing you should do actually.
- maybe you also have Gendarme rules activated in your quality profile on Sonar? (this is the case if you're using the default "Sonar way" profile)
- you may also have lots of other Sonar violations (which don't come from external tools like FxCop), ranging from detected duplications to design issues.

And to answer your last question, there's currently no way in Sonar UI to seperate violations based on the tool that generates them. The most important for Sonar users is to get the whole list of violations, whatever the tool that generates them is.

Comment: Currenlty Sonar is running this Rule "Elements must be documented" of StyleCop. Whereas Jenkins doesnt uses this rule?